# Query working in SQLPlus and SQLDeveloper but not through JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have Oracle database 12.1.0.2.0 installed with `parallel_min_percent` set to 50. (Other params are `parallel_min_servers = 24`, `parallel_max_servers = 48`)

I am trying to run below query and getting exception:

```
select constraint_name, constraint_type, table_name 
 from user_constraints where table_name = ? AND constraint_type = 'P';
```

`Table_name` is set to `'employee'`.

Note:

1. I am not getting any error while running this query from sqlplus or sqldeveloper.
2. Error is observed only while running using JDBC
3. I am not getting any error if I remove `constraint_type = 'P'` clause

> Exception: ORA-12827: insufficient parallel query slaves (requested 2,
>   available 0, parallel_min_percent 50)

How do I get it working in case of JDBC?

Also, is there a way, i can check degree of user_constraint table?

Comment: have you tried with escaping ' try select constraint_name, constraint_type, table_name from user_constraints where table_name = ? AND constraint_type = \'P\';

Comment: tried escaping \' but it did not help

Comment: What is the query you run in SQLDeveloper? Obviously it doesn't contain a `?`, so I'm wondering how you replaced that. To be exactly equivalent, you should replace it with a bind parameter, not with the `'employee'` string.

Comment: query running on SQLDeveloper is:
select constraint_name, constraint_type, table_name 
 from user_constraints where table_name = 'employee' AND constraint_type = 'P';

Comment: You should change that to `where table_name = :1` and then supply the value for the bind parameter (`:1`) when you run the query. As a side note, it would be very uncommon in Oracle to have a lowercase table name.

Comment: java code used: String query = "select constraint_name, constraint_type, table_name 
 from user_constraints where table_name = ? AND constraint_type = 'P'";                   
    ps.setString(1,tableName.toUpperCase());

Comment: And your results in SQLDeveloper using a _bind parameter_ are???

Comment: What is the result of "SELECTdegree FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'EMPLOYEE';?

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but how are you connecting to the database in all 3 instances - is the JDBC connection using pooling but SQLPLus/Dev are not?

Comment: Result using bind parameter returns no rows.

Comment: Select degree for both 'EMPLOYEE' and 'USER_CONSTRAINT' table returns no result. In fact there is no table named EMPLOYEE. I am expecting it to run successfully instead of throwing error

Comment: do you connect with the same user in all cases?

Comment: yes. I think this is an issue with user_constraint table.Oracle SR number.
SR 3-10473641961